# HP Pavilion does not boot

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion

I own a HP Pavilion DV5 notebook. Yesterday evening, everything was working perfectly. Today, it does not boot.

It does not boot from HDD and any CD. Yes, I tried connecting HDD to another PC, it worked perfectly. Same thing for CD device and CDs. I ran HDD and memory tests, both were passed.

Generally, after HP splash screen appears (screen when you can press Escape key to enter menu and BIOS), there's black screen. I tried to remove RAM and mix it as well. Without any luck. Same thing for Wireless card (there's still red wifi icon on the notebook, but I can't remember when it was switching to blue).

Any ideas how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Reverse minority report error!... (Couldn't think of anything funnier!)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the BIOS to all default options? Long shot, but could help.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong here, but the last time I looked at a HP laptop, the diagnostic tools that you can select from BIOS are located on the hard drive. If however you cannot boot from CD, I would make sure that the disk is bootable and you have actually selected it as the boot device.

However, next time you boot, try pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> repeatedly until you see the Windows Boot menu - try selecting `Disable restart on system failure` to see if you can see any more information.

However, it may be worth seeing if you can get in to the restore program (also selectable from that boot menu) in order to reinstall Windows - just in case it is corrupt (take a backup of your files first).

If you can access the hard drive, which I think it can - this should bring the machine back. If it can't then try again booting from CD, making sure you are actually selecting it as the boot drive.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tools are located on the hard drive. Why? Because I inserted brand new blank hard drive and still have access to the tools. However, laptop passed all tests. I tried to boot from HDD,. tried to boot from CD. Yes I'm sure I selected corect option. Anyway, without any luck. Really weird for me, it was working yesterday. Today morning, it's not.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have two system installed on this PC, Windows Seven and Linux so after summary splash screen GRUB should load.